# Show that collection of all prime power elements form a Sylow subgroup

Tags: group-theory

I was proving the result that every finite abelian group $G$ is isomorphic to direct product of its Sylow subgroups and I have a solution which prove it by just showing that $G$ is internal direct product of $A_{p_1}$, $A_{p_2},\ldots,A_{p_k}$ for some primes $p_1$, $p_2,\ldots,p_k$,
where 
$$A_p=\{x \in G\mid \text{order}(x)=p^a,\text{ where }a \text{ is some positive integer}\}$$ 
I am wondering  why $A_p$ is Sylow $p$-subgroup.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: My question is "my teacher proves the result that every finite abelian group can be written as direct product of its Sylow subgroups and at the end he shows that it is direct product of all Ap's ,now the question arises whether these Ap's are Sylow subgroups?

Comment: Please make one correction 'a' is some non negative integer and not positive as defined in Ap